# In Splendor can we have more than 3 joker (gold) tokens in our hand without spending them?

Tags: splendor

the situation arrived when a player had one reserved card but already 3 joker tokens and wanted to reserve another card. can he receive a gold token even if he already has 3 in his hand?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can have more than 3 joker tokens.

In the list of things you can do on a turn, the rules say:

> - Reserve 1 development card and take 1 gold token (joker)

The rules later restrict when you can reserve a card:

> Players may not have more than three reserved cards in hand

There is no mention of a limit on the number of jokers*. There is only a limit on the number of reserved cards in hand.

*Note that jokers do still count towards the normal 10-token limit. If you are at 10 tokens already, you can still reserve a card and take a joker, but you will then have to discard a token to get back down to 10.

Comment: Note that there is a limit on the number of tokens you can have (10), but that does not prevent you from taking additional ones. You must simply discard any excess tokens at the end of your turn.

Comment: The only time you can’t draw a joker is if there are none in reserve otherwise you just draw and immediately discard back down to 10. I have confirmed in the ios app that you can get a joker or draw three tokens with 10 in your hand.

Comment: We use a house rule that you can't, because especially in a four-player game, it can be quite effective to hoard the tokens to dissuade other players from reserving cards.